# PyXB - AssertionError: No element bindings in http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml

Tags: python, wsdl, pyxb

I am attempting to generate bindings for a WSDL with PyXB, and it is giving the AssertionError exception in the title.

My understanding, based on the PyXB documentation, is that the bundle archive for http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml is included with PyXB. However, something appears to be wrong. It either does not get used, or it has incorrect contents.

I use the following command line to attempt to generate the bindings:

```
python c:\Python27\Scripts\pyxbgen.py --wsdl-location=http://xx.xxx.xxx.xxx/YYY.asmx?WSDL --module=client --write-for-customization
```

The traceback:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "c:\Python27\Scripts\pyxbgen.py", line 51, in <module> generator.resolveExternalSchema()
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\generate.py", line 2647, in resolveExternalSchema
schema = converter(self, sl)
File "c:\Python27\Scripts\pyxbgen.py", line 28, in WSDLToSchema
spec = wsdl.definitions.createFromDOM(pyxb.utils.domutils.StringToDOM(xmld,
location_base=wsdl_uri), process_schema=True, generation_uid=generator.generationUID())
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\basis.py", line 1767, in createFromDOM
return self._createFromDOM(node, expanded_name, **kw)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\basis.py", line 1791, in _createFromDOM
return element.CreateDOMBinding(node, self.elementForName(expanded_name), **kw)
File "c:\Python27\lib\site-packages\pyxb\binding\basis.py", line 1735, in elementForName
assert 'elementBinding' in elt_en.namespace()._categoryMap(), 'No element bindings in %s' % (elt_en.namespace(),)
AssertionError: No element bindings in http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml
```

In addition, I set the PYXB_ARCHIVE_PATH environment variable to:

```
C:\Python27\Lib\site-packages\pyxb\bundles\common\raw
```

I am not sure if this is the correct way to do this. I also tried specifying the --archive-path command line option as well, but I got the same error back.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Probably you need to use:

```
--archive-path=${PYXB_ROOT}/pyxb/bundles/common//:+
```

as the argument.  This recursively searches for available namespaces in the common bundles first, then includes any other search paths.  There's an [example in the manual](http://pyxb.sourceforge.net/userref_pyxbgen.html#schemas-defined-in-wsdl-documents) that's close to this.